# Link Tables with Properties in EF6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, entity-framework-6, code-first

I currently have a situation with code first EF6 where I need to create a many-to-many mapping (easy enough) however the generated relationship table needs to contain properties of its own. Here's a simplified example of what I have:

```
public class Journey : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Point> Points { get; set; }
}

public class Point : Entity
{
    public DbGeography GeoLocation { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Journey> Journeys { get; set; }
}
```

*The "Entity" class basically contains the primary key.*

This would of course create a relationship table with foreign keys for the "Point" and "Journey" table primary keys. Great, but what if I want to add properties to that link table? Such as a `DateTime` property called `ArrivalDate` which holds the time of arrival at that point.

You could argue that I can add that property to the "Point" class **but** I want this table to hold a list of all physical points used in my application, without duplicates (a single point could be used in multiple journeys, each with different arrival dates). Therefor I need to hold this property elsewhere, the link table would be ideal here.

The only solution I can think of would be to create an actual relationship class:

```
public class JourneyPoint : Entity
{
    public int JourneyId { get; set; }
    public int PointId { get; set; }

    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Journey Journey { get; set; }
    public virtual Point Point { get; set; }
}
```

And then modify my `Journey` and `Point` classes to have a one-to-many relationship with the `JourneyPoint` class. However this just adds complication and isn't particularly semantic:

```
...
Journey myJourney = aMethodToGetMyJourney();
Point firstPoint = myJourney.JourneyPoints[0].Point.
...
```

That doesn't seems to make much sense and could confuse other developers. Is what I'm asking for possible at all?

Comment: creating the `JourneyPoint` class is the only solution.

Comment: If you are worried about semantics, check this article out. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/